# tinymce selection_toolbar with default theme(modern)

Tags: tinymce-4

selection_toolbar property only works with inlite theme. Is there any way to make it work for the default theme which is modern ?

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'div.tinymce',
  /* theme: 'inlite',*/
  inline: true,
  selection_toolbar: 'bold italic | quicklink h2 h3 blockquote'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `selection_toolbar` is only available in the inlite mode.  If you wanted to use it in another mode you would have to write the code to do that yourself.

You could also submit a feature request here:  [GitHub Issue Tracker](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues)

Comment: Thanks Michael, I will try to implement the feature.